# combine two ffmpeg -vf filters into one in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, batch

I have two video filters that work as long as I use them in separate batch files and I can't find a way to combine them. The first filter resizes JPG images and then creates a slideshow of them incl. crossfade transitions:

```
-reinit_filter 0 -r .3 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf zoompan=d=(6+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -r 25 "Slideshow 1080.mkv"
```

Issue is that images that don't have AR of 16:9 will get stretched vertically or horizontally to fill the frame. On the other hand, the following command creates a slideshow **with no crossfade transitions** between the images but it it retains the correct aspect ratio of all images by letterboxing/pillarboxing them:

```
-r .3 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black" -r 25 "Slideshow 1080.mkv"
```

How can I combine both cammands/filters in a single batch command to achieve correct AR for all images AND have them crossfaded? I tried to put them behind each other separated by a comma but that didn't work.

This is log when running command from answer 1:

```
E:\batch file testing>start /b /low "ffmpeg" "C:\AVConvert\ffmpeg.exe" -reinit_f
ilter 0 -r .25 -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_image_list_JPG.txt -c:v libx264 -crf
23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad
=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black,zoompan=d=(4+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:
interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -r 25 "Slideshow 1080.mkv"

E:\batch file testing>PAUSE
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . . ffmpeg version 5.0-essentials_build-www.g
yan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32thr
eads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --e
nable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-
libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable
-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg
--enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enabl
e-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm -
-enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va
--enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libo
pencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --e
nable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --ena
ble-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from 'concat_image_list_JPG.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 5
184x2920, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000000033dc7c0] [swscaler @ 00000000033e97c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000000033dc7c0] [swscaler @ 0000000003496bc0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000000033dc7c0] [swscaler @ 0000000003550e00] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000000033dc7c0] [swscaler @ 00000000069400c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000000033dc7c0] [swscaler @ 00000000069f52c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_framerate_3 @ 00000000006d9700] time base:2/1 -> 1/25 exact:1
[Parsed_framerate_3 @ 00000000006d9700] fps -> fps:25/1 scene score:100.000000 i
nterpolate start:0 end:255
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] 264 - core 164 r3081 19856cc - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'Slideshow 1080.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080,
 q=2-31, 25 fps, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
frame=   58 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=  24.2kbits/
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] filter context - w: 5184 h: 2
920 fmt: 13, incoming frame - w: 5184 h: 2920 fmt: 12 pts_time: 4
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] Changing video frame properti
es on the fly is not supported by all filters.
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000034d7bc0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035b00c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000069557c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000034d7bc0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035b00c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000069557c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000034dd740] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003425580] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035b00c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
frame=  102 fps= 81 q=28.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=   2.5kbits/
frame=  132 fps= 75 q=28.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=   1.5kbits/
frame=  157 fps= 67 q=28.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate=   1.2kbits/
frame=  174 fps= 60 q=28.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:04.84 bitrate=   1.0kbits/
frame=  188 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.40 bitrate= 776.6kbits/
frame=  206 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:06.12 bitrate= 685.2kbits/
frame=  248 fps= 55 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:07.80 bitrate= 537.7kbits/
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] filter context - w: 5184 h: 2
920 fmt: 13, incoming frame - w: 3000 h: 2000 fmt: 14 pts_time: 8
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] Changing video frame properti
es on the fly is not supported by all filters.
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077ca5c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000697e040] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003425580] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035b00c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077ca5c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000697e040] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003425580] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035b00c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003445680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000697be40] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000034d9540] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000003408240] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
frame=  282 fps= 56 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:09.16 bitrate= 457.8kbits/
frame=  305 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:10.08 bitrate=1040.2kbits/
frame=  318 fps= 52 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:10.60 bitrate= 989.1kbits/
frame=  333 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:11.20 bitrate= 936.1kbits/
frame=  348 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:11.80 bitrate= 888.5kbits/
frame=  384 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:13.24 bitrate= 791.9kbits/
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] filter context - w: 5184 h: 2
920 fmt: 13, incoming frame - w: 2244 h: 888 fmt: 14 pts_time: 12
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] Changing video frame properti
es on the fly is not supported by all filters.
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000351ab80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077f0900] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000035777c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000006ddd40] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077d0b80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a31280] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a04d80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000351ab80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077ca5c0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000077ee700] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a02b80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
frame=  424 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:14.84 bitrate=1837.0kbits/
frame=  454 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:16.04 bitrate=1699.6kbits/
frame=  470 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:16.68 bitrate=1634.4kbits/
frame=  485 fps= 49 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:17.28 bitrate=1577.6kbits/
frame=  502 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=1517.9kbits/
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] filter context - w: 5184 h: 2
920 fmt: 13, incoming frame - w: 4976 h: 2800 fmt: 12 pts_time: 16
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000006d9800] Changing video frame properti
es on the fly is not supported by all filters.
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000351ab80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000006ddd40] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006b93080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 000000000351ab80] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000006dfc00] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006b91c00] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000029d85d00] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a21000] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000069c8cc0] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006a2f080] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 00000000034dd680] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000000000699ae80] [swscaler @ 0000000006b91c00] deprecated pixel for
mat used, make sure you did set range correctly
frame=  552 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate=1891.1kbits/
frame=  601 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:21.92 bitrate=1722.0kbits/
frame=  628 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:23.00 bitrate=1641.2kbits/
frame=  657 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:24.16 bitrate=1562.4kbits/
frame=  728 fps= 56 q=28.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:27.00 bitrate=1786.4kbits/
frame=  750 fps= 56 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5980kB time=00:00:29.88 bitrate=1639.5kbits
/s speed=2.24x
video:5975kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.094786%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] frame I:3     Avg QP:16.07  size:230264
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] frame P:269   Avg QP:19.24  size: 19490
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] frame B:478   Avg QP:22.64  size:   385
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] consecutive B-frames: 12.8%  5.3%  4.0% 77.9%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] mb I  I16..4: 19.2% 54.7% 26.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] mb P  I16..4:  1.3%  2.5%  0.3%  P16..4: 25.4%  3.5
%  4.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:62.8%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.9%  0.0
%  0.0%  direct: 0.3%  skip:96.7%  L0:11.6% L1:85.0% BI: 3.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] 8x8 transform intra:59.9% inter:67.8%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.4% 48.0% 20.3% inter: 6
.6% 8.7% 1.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 54% 22%  7% 17%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 16% 31%  5%  5%
 7%  6%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 20% 16%  5%  8%
10%  8%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 19% 18%  3%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:33.5% UV:32.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] ref P L0: 55.3% 24.3% 19.5%  0.7%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] ref B L0: 81.6% 16.4%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] ref B L1: 95.9%  4.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000066e2c0] kb/s:1631.27
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the scale and pad before zoompan.

`-vf scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black,zoompan=d=(6+2)/2:s=1920x1080:fps=1/2,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100`

Comment: This solution doesn't correctly (symmetrically) letterbox/pillarbox images. It adds green space to the right of an image instead of black space on both sides. The image's AR is correct, though. Following images will get squeezed and shifted into the wrong pillarbox space from the preceding image so that images get smaller and smaller as the sequence progresses. If I change the order of the two commands, AR is not retained any more.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: SHered full log in original question.

Comment: Some of your frames have different pixel formats. Insert `format=yuv444p` before the scale.

Comment: There's already `-pix_fmt yuv420p` in my original command sequence. Do I replace that one or how do I merge your suggested command? Replacing `-pix_fmt yuv420p` by `-pix_fmt yuv444p` doesn't help and yields the same result of shrinking images..

Comment: Insert `format=yuv444p` filter before the scale.

Comment: `[Parsed_format_0 @ 00000000035140c0] Option 'scale' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000007a3640] Error initializing filter 'format' with args
'yuv444p:scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Comma instead of colon after yuv444p

Comment: images don't keep AR any more.